# Api platform applying filters to custom queries inside controller and or providers

Tags: php, symfony, orm, api-platform.com

I need todo some custom queries but i want to keep the benefits of API platform suchs as the filters.
Going through the docs and searching online, There little to no information on how you can use your own query / repository and applying the filters from API platform upon it.

```
<?php

namespace App\State;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\State\Options;
use ApiPlatform\Exception\RuntimeException;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Util\QueryNameGenerator;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Extension\QueryResultCollectionExtensionInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Resource\Factory\ResourceMetadataCollectionFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\State\LinksHandlerTrait;

final class Provider implements ProviderInterface
{
    use LinksHandlerTrait;

    /**
     * @param QueryCollectionExtensionInterface[] $collectionExtensions
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceMetadataCollectionFactoryInterface $resourceMetadataCollectionFactory, private readonly ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry, private readonly iterable $collectionExtensions = [])
    {
        $this->resourceMetadataCollectionFactory = $resourceMetadataCollectionFactory;
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): iterable
    {
        $entityClass = $operation->getClass();
        if (($options = $operation->getStateOptions()) && $options instanceof Options && $options->getEntityClass()) {
            $entityClass = $options->getEntityClass();
        }

        /** @var EntityManagerInterface $manager */
        $manager = $this->managerRegistry->getManagerForClass($entityClass);

        $repository = $manager->getRepository($entityClass);
        if (!method_exists($repository, 'createQueryBuilder')) {
            throw new RuntimeException('The repository class must have a "createQueryBuilder" method.');
        }

        $queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('o');
        $queryNameGenerator = new QueryNameGenerator();

        $this->handleLinks($queryBuilder, $uriVariables, $queryNameGenerator, $context, $entityClass, $operation);

        foreach ($this->collectionExtensions as $extension) {
            $extension->applyToCollection($queryBuilder, $queryNameGenerator, $entityClass, $operation, $context);

            if ($extension instanceof QueryResultCollectionExtensionInterface && $extension->supportsResult($entityClass, $operation, $context)) {
                return $extension->getResult($queryBuilder, $entityClass, $operation, $context);
            }
        }

        return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Patch;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\ModelRepository;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GetCollection;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use App\State\Provider;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ModelRepository::class)]
#[GetCollection(
    provider: Provider::class,
)]

class Model
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    #[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, strategy: 'exact')]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $date = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): static
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): static
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Tried to manipulate classes.
Dumping context to see if there is any reference to the filters, There is a string tried searching online for anything related to it couldn't find anything.
Attempted todo the same inside a controller with no results.

No errors and empty collectionExtensions.
Tried to inject the filter no results.

Expecting to be able to run custom queries while applying the filters to the query.

Answer (score 0):

In your `class Model` example, you can only apply filters to the class it self. Not one of its properties (as per your example). This can also be found in the documentation:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#search-filter

Your `class Model` is also missing the `#[ApiResource]` attribute.

Concluding, your class should look something like this:

```
#[ApiResource]
#[ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties: ['title' => 'exact'])]
class Model
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATE_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $date = null;

    (...)
}
```

You can also create your own filters. It is explained in the documentation:
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#creating-custom-filters

Comment: Yea im aware of it, The problem is that i want to  use these filters in my own queries.
I got it somewhat working atm, Though very hacky.

You can get the context and in there you can find the filters and then have to manually add these filters to an query, Does the trick though i suspect that API platform has someway of doing this its just not documented as of this time.

Answer (score -3):

I had perform something very similar, but using a custom endpoint and a controller.
To filter your data based on a query parameter in Symfony with API Platform, you can follow these steps:

1. Define the Filter in the Entity:
   In your entity, you need to define the filter you want to use. For example a boolean filter, you can use BooleanFilter like this:

   namespace App\Entity;

   use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
   use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\BooleanFilter;

   #[ApiResource(
   operations: [
   new GetCollection(
   name: "MyReadSubmission",
   uriTemplate: '/MyBlogPostCustom',
   controller: MyBlogPostController::class,
   ),
   ]
   )]

   #[ApiFilter(BooleanFilter::class, properties: ["isPublished"])]
   class BlogPost
   {
   // ... other annotations and properties ...
   }
2. Update the Controller:
   In your controller, retrieve the query parameter and use it to filter your data:

   namespace App\Controller;

   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
   use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
   use App\Entity\User;
   use App\Entity\BlogPost;
   use App\Repository\BlogPostRepository;

   #[AsController]
   class MyBlogPostController extends AbstractController
   {
   private $entityManager;

   ```
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager){
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function __invoke(Request $request): array
    {
        // Retrieve the filter parameter from the request
        $isPublished = $request->query->get('isPublished');

        // Use the filter parameter to retrieve the data
        $MyBlogPosts = $this->entityManager->getRepository(BlogPost::class)->findByUserAndPublicationStatus($isPublished);

        return ($MyBlogPosts);
    }
   ```

   }
3. Update the Repository:
   Ensure your repository method can handle the filter parameter:

namespace App\Repository;

class BlogPostRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
// ... other methods ...

```
public function findByUserAndPublicationStatus($isPublished): array
{
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        

    if ($isPublished !== null) {
        $queryBuilder->andWhere('b.isPublished = :isPublished')
                     ->setParameter('isPublished', $isPublished);
    }

    return $queryBuilder->orderBy('b.createdAt', 'DESC')
                        ->getQuery()
                        ->getResult();
}
```

}

Endpoint:
With the above setup, you should be able to send a GET request to the following endpoint to retrieve the filtered data:

When you perform this request :
GET /MyBlogPosts?isPublished=true
The controller get the filter.